# Java jTable data from ArrayList objects and update from other methods

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I'm new to Java GUI and trying to work with jTable's in SWING. I currently have one which I made by following the Oracle tutorial and it gets the table data by using:

```
Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
};
```

I have an object called Orders which has an ArrayList (productsInOrder) which contains an unlimited number of Project objects. I am trying to get the table to display each of the following for each object in the ArrayList. productsInOrder.getPrice() productsInOrder.getSKU() productsInOrder.getName()

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or link me to a tutorial that can help as I've looked all over the internet and can not figure this out.

Finally, I have elsewhere I have an action listener which adds more Product objects to the ArrayList when the user performs certain actions. How would I update the jTable? Simply by reloading the whole jTable in the action listener or is there a way to simply add another row to the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or link me to a tutorial that can help

The tutorial you've read is the tutorial that should help you.

The basic solution is to create a custom TableModel. In the example they store the data in a 2D array. In your case the data will be stored in an ArrayList. Therefore you will need to modify the getVAlueAt() method to access the ArrayList instead of the 2D array.

> Finally, I have elsewhere I have an action listener which adds more Product objects to the ArrayList when the user performs certain actions.

Your code should update the TableModel, not the ArrayList. Then the table model will notify the table. This means you need to implement an addRow(...) method in your custom TableModel.

For a more complex solution you can create a generic table model which can be used. See the [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) for an example of this approach. The JButtonTableModel example code shows how you can further customize the BeanTableModel for only the properties you are interested in.

Comment: @Joseph Flynn I voting for http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/ChristmasTree/ @camickr +1

Comment: @camickr - Thanks for pointing me back to that tutorial, a re-read has been a great help. The one bit I still don't understand is hot to update the table. I use the ArrayList elsewhere, so should I update bother the ArrayList and the addRow(...) method in the custom TableModel? Is this bad coding practice as it will duplicate the code? Thanks.

Comment: As I suggested you should be updating the TableModel directly, NOT the ArrayList. The RowTableModel has methods like addRow(), and removeRow() so you can access the individual objects. If you update the ArrayList directly, the TableModel has no idea the data has changed. In this case, everwhere in your code that you update the ArrayList, you would also need to invoke a table.repaint() to force repainting of the entire table which is not a good idea because in a MVC design it is the responsibility of the model to notify the view when the data has changed.

Answer (score 0):

[The Definitive Guide to Swing](http://www.apress.com/9781590594476) by John Zukowski is an excellent resource on Swing. It addresses everything very methodically with relevant examples. Highly recommend it.